# Why doesn't `coerce` implicitly apply Compose to these functions?

Tags: haskell, applicative

Consider this type:

```
data Vec3 = Vec3 {_x, _y, _z :: Int}
```

I have some functions that all take the same input, and may fail to compute a field:

```
data Input
getX, getY, getZ :: Input -> Maybe Int
```

I can write a function that tries all three of these field constructors:

```
v3 :: Input -> Maybe Vec3
v3 i = liftA3 Vec3 (getX i) (getY i) (getZ i)
```

But it's kinda annoying to have to pass that `i` input around three times. Functions are themselves an applicative functor, and so one can replace `foo x = bar (f x) (g x) (h x)` with `foo = liftA3 bar f g h`.

Here, my `bar` is `liftA3 Vec3`, so I could write

```
v3' :: Input -> Maybe Vec3
v3' = liftA3 (liftA3 Vec3) getX getY getZ
```

But this is a bit gross, and when we work with composed applicatives in this way (`((->) Input)` and `Maybe`), there's the `Compose` newtype to handle this kind of thing. With it, I can write

```
v3'' :: Input -> Maybe Vec3
v3'' = getCompose go
  where go = liftA3 Vec3 x y z
        x = Compose getX
        y = Compose getY
        z = Compose getZ
```

Okay, not exactly a great character savings, but we're now working with one combined functor instead of two, which is nice. And I thought I could use `coerce` to win me back some of the characters: after all, `x` is just a newtype wrapper around `getX`, and likewise for the other fields. So I thought I could coerce `liftA3` into accepting three `Input -> Maybe Vec3` instead of accepting three `Compose ((->) Input) Maybe Vec3`:

```
v3''' :: Input -> Maybe Vec3
v3''' = getCompose go
  where go = coerce liftA3 Vec3 getX getY getZ
```

But this *doesn't* work, yielding the error message:

```
tmp.hs:23:14: error:
    • Couldn't match representation of type ‘f0 c0’
                               with that of ‘Input -> Maybe Int’
        arising from a use of ‘coerce’
    • In the expression: coerce liftA3 Vec3 getX getY getZ
      In an equation for ‘go’: go = coerce liftA3 Vec3 getX getY getZ
      In an equation for ‘v3'''’:
          v3'''
            = getCompose go
            where
                go = coerce liftA3 Vec3 getX getY getZ
   |
23 |   where go = coerce liftA3 Vec3 getX getY getZ
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't understand why not. I can write `coerce getX :: Compose ((->) Input) Maybe Int`, and this is fine. And generally a function can be coerced in order to make it coerce its arguments or return type, as in

```
coerce ((+) :: Int -> Int -> Int) (Max (5::Int)) (Min (8::Int)) :: Sum Int
```

And I can in fact write out all the `coerce`s individually:

```
v3'''' :: Input -> Maybe Vec3
v3'''' = getCompose go
  where go = liftA3 Vec3 x y z
        x = coerce getX
        y = coerce getY
        z = coerce getZ
```

So why can't `liftA3` itself be coerced to accept `getX` instead of `coerce getX`, allowing me to use `v3'''`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you provide the applicative functor to `liftA3`, then the following typechecks:

```hs
v3' :: Input -> Maybe Vec3
v3' = coerce (liftA3 @(Compose ((->) Input) Maybe) Vec3) getX getY getZ
```

In `coerce liftA3` without any annotation, there is no way to infer what applicative functor to use `liftA3` with. Neither of these even mention the type `Compose`. It might just as well be `ReaderT Input Maybe`, `Kleisli Maybe Input`, another type with an unlawful instance or something even more exotic.

In `getCompose (coerce liftA3 _ _ _)` (your last attempt), the `getCompose` does not constraint `liftA3` ("inside" of `coerce`), because `getCompose` is "outside" of `coerce`. It requires that the result type of `liftA3` is coercible to `Compose ((->) Input) Maybe Vec3`, but it might still not be equal to that.

Comment: But why can't it be inferred? I agree that `coerce liftA3 Vec3 getX getY getZ` isn't enough information, but I expected the type information to flow the other way as well: the type at which I'm trying to use `coerce` is constrained by the fact that I've declared that `getCompose go` has type `Input -> Maybe Vec3`.

Comment: @amalloy In `liftA3`, there are multiple `f`s that are constrained to be equal to each other, so information can flow from the "output" `f` to the inputs. But `coerce liftA3` doesn't share that property -- maybe you wanted different choices of `newtype` than `Compose` for those!

Comment: @amalloy Concretely, if `F a` also shares a representation with `Input -> Maybe a`, then `liftA3 :: (Int -> Int -> Int -> Vec3) -> F Int -> F Int -> F Int -> F Vec3` can *also* be `coerce`d to the type required in the spot it's used.

Comment: @DanielWagner Right, I think that clears it up. I was "wishing" that GHC would know I only wanted to coerce input arguments to `liftA3`, and that my desired output type would guide inference on what I want to coerce to. But sadly, `coerce` is more powerful: I might have intended to coerce the inputs to some other `f` type, apply `liftA3`, and then coerce its output to match the expected `Compose` signature.

Comment: @amalloy For what it's worth, I find this to be a general principle with `coerce`. It never *quite* gets nailed down how I wanted it to. I've tried several times to work out a general principle describing what I want and, beyond some vague hand gesturing, have never really gotten anywhere.

Comment: This code snippet doesn't compile here. If I'm reading the type error correctly, I believe it's because which `Int` newtype wrapper `liftA3` is supposed to use isn't specified yet. Yikers. (Presumably a similar situation will come up for the `Vec3` part as well.) Would be nice for GHC to be willing to do "defaulting" or something like it when the `Coercible` constraint is on an otherwise parametrically polymorphic type...

Comment: @DanielWagner In some cases, a way to limit the generality of `coerce` might be to write a type family which relates input and output types.

Comment: I think the problem is that in `getCompose (coerce liftA3 ...)` you *could* be coercing the `liftA3` that works on `Compose` to accept `Input -> Maybe Vec3` instead (and return a `Compose` as normal, for the `getCompose` to unpack). But you might also be coercing an entirely different `liftA3` (say, the one that goes with the `IO` Applicative), and thus *also* be coercing the return value to `Compose`. Either of those are just different choices for type variables in `coerce :: Coercible a b => a -> b`; neither is a priori preferred, only once we go actually looking for `Coercible` instances.

Comment: And as we know, GHC will **not** examine all of the possible choices for type variables to see if there is only one possibility that has a matching instance. It wants a polymorphic instance that matches the variables, or it wants the variables to already be instantiated by something else.